# changing nested child div based on parent divs

Tags: html, css

I need to find a workable solution to change the color on some text within nested repeated divs so that based on the parent div the child div can be set individually

EDIT: I made a typo in my original example... here is the actual code im using and the css and i just cant get it right....

```
<div class="productOption">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="productOptionDetails">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="Add">
            <input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="2 Hours">
            <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="220">
            <input type="hidden" name="productSize" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="productWeight" value="">
            <div class="productOptionName">2 Hours</div>
            <div class="productOptionSize">1</div>
            <div class="productOptionCode">2hr</div>
            <div class="productOptionPrice">$220.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionOrder">
            <div class="productOptionQty">
                <input id="qtyfield" type="text" name="qty" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="addtocart">
                <button class="productD_order" type="submit" value="Order Online">Add To &nbsp;<img src="himages/cart-icon.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionDetails">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="Add">
            <input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="2 Hours">
            <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="220">
            <input type="hidden" name="productSize" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="productWeight" value="">
            <div class="productOptionName">2 Hours</div>
            <div class="productOptionSize">1</div>
            <div class="productOptionCode">2hr</div>
            <div class="productOptionPrice">$220.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionOrder">
            <div class="productOptionQty">
                <input id="qtyfield" type="text" name="qty" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="addtocart">
                <button class="productD_order" type="submit" value="Order Online">Add To &nbsp;<img src="himages/cart-icon.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionDetails">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="Add">
            <input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="2 Hours">
            <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="220">
            <input type="hidden" name="productSize" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="productWeight" value="">
            <div class="productOptionName">2 Hours</div>
            <div class="productOptionSize">1</div>
            <div class="productOptionCode">2hr</div>
            <div class="productOptionPrice">$220.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionOrder">
            <div class="productOptionQty">
                <input id="qtyfield" type="text" name="qty" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="addtocart">
                <button class="productD_order" type="submit" value="Order Online">Add To &nbsp;<img src="himages/cart-icon.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </form>
</div>
```

```
.productOption:nth-child(1) > form > .productOptionDetails > .productOptionName { color:#049b5c;}
.productOption:nth-child(2) > form > .productOptionDetails > .productOptionName { color:#0482fa;}
.productOption:nth-child(3) > form > .productOptionDetails > .productOptionName { color:#5802b4;}
.productOption:nth-child(4) > form > .productOptionDetails > .productOptionName { color:#df041b;}
.productOption:nth-child(5) > form > .productOptionDetails > .productOptionName { color:#02417D;}
.productOption:nth-child(6) > form > .productOptionDetails > .productOptionName { color:#fff600;}
```

all this does is make each of the .productOptionName text colors to the first one which is green

can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Voting to close because of typo.

Comment: You've got to be kicking yourself after looking at Terminator's answer. We all do it; it took me a while to find it too. :)

Comment: ok that was simply a typo in my example... here is the actual code im using and the css and i just cant get it right....


```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you define six different styles for `.productOptionName` when there are only three such divs in your example. I'm assuming your want to color those three divs all a different color without adding an id or extra class to them.

Right now you are trying to select the nth child that also has a class of `.productOption` with the `.productOption:nth-child(n)` selector. You only have one div with class `.productOption` which in this case is the first child (of the body) so only your first line of CSS will be executed:

```
.productOption:nth-child(1) > form > .productOptionDetails > .productOptionName { color:#049b5c;}
```

This line of CSS will select the `.productOption` div, then the `form` inside of it. Then all the divs with class `.productOptionDetails`, and then all divs inside of those with class `.productOptionName`, coloring them `#049b5c`.

If you want to color all three divs with class `.productOptionName` in your example a different color, try the below example. This selects the div with class `.productOption`, then the `form` inside of it. Then uses the `nth-child()` selector to select child one, three and five that also have a class of `.productOptionDetails`, and selects the `.productOptionName` inside of those.

```css
.productOption > form > .productOptionDetails:nth-child(1) > .productOptionName { color:red;}
.productOption > form > .productOptionDetails:nth-child(3) > .productOptionName { color:blue;}
.productOption > form > .productOptionDetails:nth-child(5) > .productOptionName { color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="productOption">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="productOptionDetails">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="Add">
            <input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="2 Hours">
            <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="220">
            <input type="hidden" name="productSize" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="productWeight" value="">
            <div class="productOptionName">2 Hours</div>
            <div class="productOptionSize">1</div>
            <div class="productOptionCode">2hr</div>
            <div class="productOptionPrice">$220.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionOrder">
            <div class="productOptionQty">
                <input id="qtyfield" type="text" name="qty" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="addtocart">
                <button class="productD_order" type="submit" value="Order Online">Add To &nbsp;<img src="himages/cart-icon.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionDetails">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="Add">
            <input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="2 Hours">
            <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="220">
            <input type="hidden" name="productSize" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="productWeight" value="">
            <div class="productOptionName">2 Hours</div>
            <div class="productOptionSize">1</div>
            <div class="productOptionCode">2hr</div>
            <div class="productOptionPrice">$220.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionOrder">
            <div class="productOptionQty">
                <input id="qtyfield" type="text" name="qty" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="addtocart">
                <button class="productD_order" type="submit" value="Order Online">Add To &nbsp;<img src="himages/cart-icon.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionDetails">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="Add">
            <input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="2 Hours">
            <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="220">
            <input type="hidden" name="productSize" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="productWeight" value="">
            <div class="productOptionName">2 Hours</div>
            <div class="productOptionSize">1</div>
            <div class="productOptionCode">2hr</div>
            <div class="productOptionPrice">$220.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="productOptionOrder">
            <div class="productOptionQty">
                <input id="qtyfield" type="text" name="qty" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="addtocart">
                <button class="productD_order" type="submit" value="Order Online">Add To &nbsp;<img src="himages/cart-icon.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: that was a typo in the example only...i replaced it with my actual code and it doesnt work... possibly because the divs have a form tag in it?

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer. If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted and possibly vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

example for explicit direct child

```css
.parent:nth-child(1) > .levelone > .leveltwo {
  color: red;
}
.parent:nth-child(2) > .levelone > .leveltwo {
  color: blue;
}
```

example for more generic approach but reduces bloated css

```css
.parent:nth-child(1) .leveltwo {
  color: red;
}
.parent:nth-child(2) .leveltwo {
  color: blue;
}
```